# How iterate pending limit orders

Tags: pine-script

I want to iterate placed but not filled limit orders.

```
//@version=5
strategy("How iterate pending limit orders", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

sma_fast = ta.sma(close, 14)
sma_slow = ta.sma(close, 28)
plot(sma_fast, "Fast SMA", color.yellow)
plot(sma_slow, "Slow SMA", color.blue)

longCondition = ta.crossover(sma_fast, sma_slow)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.order("Long Limit 1", strategy.long, qty=0.001, limit=close*0.99)
    strategy.order("Long Limit 2", strategy.long, qty=0.002, limit=close*0.98)
    strategy.order("Long Limit 3", strategy.long, qty=0.003, limit=close*0.97)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(sma_fast, sma_slow)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.order("Short Limit 1", strategy.short, qty=0.001, limit=close*1.01)
    strategy.order("Short Limit 2", strategy.short, qty=0.002, limit=close*1.02)
    strategy.order("Short Limit 3", strategy.short, qty=0.003, limit=close*1.03)
```

How to iterate pending limit orders that have not been filled?